# Can I have separate gradle.properties for CI and AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, continuous-integration

Currently, I have one `gradle.properties` file. It configured specifically for CI with low available memory, because otherwise CI will crash

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

However, when I make builds on the local machine it is very slow and local machine allows more memory use. Can I have separate `gradle.properties` for CI and AndroidStudio?

Comment: I think you can add Gradle.properties in C:/users/<you>/.Gradle same for your CI and those would be specific, to the machine it runs on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties), you can have multiple `gradle.properties` files. One in your project directory and one in user home directory.

As it's said:

> The configuration is applied in following order (if an option is configured in multiple locations the last one wins):
>
> - from gradle.properties in project build dir.
> - from gradle.properties in gradle user home.

In your case, you cam place CI-specific properties into the gradle.properties under user home on CI-server. This properties will be specific for CI-server and take over local properties stored under VCS.